# How to delete all the triggers and procedures from a single table?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a problem where I need to rename the table name. The table has few triggers and procedures attach to it.

My steps to do that:

1. Delete all the triggers and procedures of the table name employee.
2. Rename table name(employee) to user using ALTER command.
3. Then create all the triggers and procedures according to the new table.

Database I am using is postgresql.
Below query is used to delete the single trigger on a table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_employee_changes on employee;
```

But I want to delete all the triggers and procedures related to the given table in a single query.

Comment: You could create table t2 as select * from t; drop t2; then do your step 3.  There is no single query you drop all triggers, you can drop them all in a single transaction either writing them out like above or generate a string that contain all your drop statements then execute that string.

Comment: You do not need to drop the existing triggers nor the functions. The renamed tables will still have the same triggers and those triggers will still call the same trigger function. This is of course is subject to the internals of the those functions and your organization naming standards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to drop the triggers and functions. Just use a transaction:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION /* function that uses the new name */
...

COMMIT;
```

You only have to replace the trigger functions and other functions. Triggers, views etc. don't have to be modified.